# Unexpected behavior in dplyr::group_by_ and dplyr::summarise_

Tags: r, dplyr

I wrote this little function to find the R-squared value of a regression performed on two variables in the `mtcars` data set, which is included in R by default:

```
get_r_squared = function(x) summary(lm(mpg ~ hp, data = x))$r.squared
```

It seems to work as expected when I give it the full data set:

```
get_r_squared(mtcars)
# [1] 0.6024373
```

However, if I try to use it as part of a `dplyr` pipeline on a subset of the data, it returns the same answer as above three times when I expected it to return a different value for each subset.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by_("cyl") %>% 
  summarise_(r_squared = get_r_squared(.))

## Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
## 
##   cyl r_squared
## 1   4 0.6024373
## 2   6 0.6024373
## 3   8 0.6024373
```

I was expecting the values to look like this instead

```
sapply(
  unique(mtcars$cyl),
  function(cyl){
    get_r_squared(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == cyl, ])
  }
)
# [1] 0.01614624 0.27405583 0.08044919
```

I've confirmed that this is not a `plyr` namespace issue: that package is not loaded.

```
search() 

##  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:knitr"     "package:dplyr"    
##  [4] "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
##  [7] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
## [10] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

I'm not sure what's going on here.  Could it be related to nonstandard evaluation in the `lm` function? Or am I just misunderstanding how `group_by` works? Or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how `summarise()` works - it doesn't do anything with `.`, and the fact that it works at all is just happy chance. Instead, try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
get_r_squared <- function(x, y) summary(lm(x ~ y))$r.squared
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(r_squared = get_r_squared(mpg, wt))
```

Comment: Thanks (+1).  Is there a place where I can read more about how summarise *does* work? I don't see anything about why it couldn't use `.` in the documentation.  Sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: It doesn't say that you can use . - I can't document all the things that don't work ;)

Comment: I must have a deeper misunderstanding then.  I thought `.` always worked with `%>%`.  Looks like I need to do more reading.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it does - but it always refers to the same data frame, which doesn't change by group

Comment: Okay, I think that's where my misunderstanding was.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

Try with `do`

```
mtcars %>%
     group_by(cyl) %>% 
     do(data.frame(r_squared=get_r_squared(.)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick (+1).  Any idea *why* it doesn't work with summarize? Also, any idea how I could do it without nonstandard evaluation? I get an error when I try using `do_` instead.

Comment: To clarify, I get an error if I use `do_`  with `data.frame`, and the same answer I get with `summarise` if I skip that function.

Comment: Looks like `do(~data.frame(r_squared=get_r_squared(.)))` works.  Still not sure what went wrong with `summarise`, though...

Comment: @DavidJ.Harris   I was a bit busy in the morning as I had to catch a train.  You got the `summarise` option from Hadley.  Did you use the same code with `do_` or a different one?  If you look at the `?do`, ` do_(.data, ..., .dots)`